# Switch the vowels in the same word

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can i switch the vowels in a string to where the first vowel is switch with the last vowel and the second vowel is switched with the second to last vowel and so on and so forth? I've tried to split the input string and attempt an embedded for loop, but I can't seem to figure out where to go from there.

```
function reverseVowels(input) {
  let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
  let newArr = input.split('')
  let result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++)
      if (newArr[i] === vowels[i] && newArr[j] === vowels[i]) {
        newArr[i] = newArr[j]
      }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your loop makes no sense, you are looping from the front both times. You are also only checking to see if the vowel is the same index in the string array as in the vowels array. You should use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes and loop from both sides of your string

Comment: Can you show a few examples with  input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the vowels of the input and then reverse it. At last, replace the original arrays vowel with the filtered one.

```js
function reverseVowels(input) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  const a = input
    .split('')
    .filter((x) => vowels.includes(x))
    .reverse();
  let count = 0;
  return [...input].map((x) => (vowels.includes(x) ? a[count++] : x)).join('');
}

console.log(reverseVowels('ahije'));
console.log(reverseVowels('axeyuzi'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution I can think of is to do a sort of in place reversal where you skip any characters that are not vowels:

```js
function reverseVowels(input) {
  const vowels = new Set(['a','e','i','o','u']);
  const result = input.split('')
  const vowelIndeces = result.reduce((acc, char, i) => {
    if (vowels.has(char)) {
      acc.push(i);
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
  let i = 0;
  let j = vowelIndeces.length - 1;

  while (j > i) {
    const ref = result[vowelIndeces[i]];
    result[vowelIndeces[i]] = result[vowelIndeces[j]];
    result[vowelIndeces[j]] = ref;
    j--;
    i++;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have a runner start from each end. So `left` would start at index `0` and increase until it hit a vowel (or end of the string, but I'll let you handle edge cases). Once that happens, use a runner `right` to start at the end and decrease until it hits a vowel. Swap them and repeat until the pointers cross.